# why the value passed from forecast class showing as 0 in the Controls class. What I am doing wrong?

Tags: kivy

class Forecast(BoxLayout):
    sunrise=NumericProperty()

```
def weather_retrieved1(self, request, data):
    data = json.loads(data.decode()) if not isinstance(data, dict) else data
    #  some code here      
    self.sunrise=(data['sys']['sunrise'])
```

class Controls(BoxLayout):
    sunrise=NumericProperty()
    forecast=Forecast()

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Controls, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.forecast.bind(sunrise=self.forecast.weather_retrieved1)
   # for testing 
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.test, 1)

def test(self, *args):
    print self.sunrise # i get as an output 0
```

Comment: Please help me to understand why this doesn't work

Comment: Use an indentation of 4 spaces when submitting code to have it formatted correctly.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand what do you mean. I used four spaces, when I copied the code. When I run the program it works, the problem is that somehow I pass wrongly sunrise value and get wrong results. I look for an answer, what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.bind(sunrise=self.controls.sunrise)
```

This doesn't make sense - self.controls doesn't even have a sunrise attribute.

It also doesn't make sense because you must pass a *function* to bind, not a method. I can explain more if you fix the above problem and can't work out the rest.

Comment: Thanks, tried to fix it but still get the sunrise 0